# Why can't I view any available networks in linux

Tags: wifi, lfs, iwlwifi

I use a custom built Linux distro. When I try to enable wifi I cannot view any existing networks. My wifi card is Intel Wifi link 5100 and the output of `lspci -vv` is

```
Subsystem: Intel Corporation WiFi Link 5100 AGN
Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 35
Region 0: Memory at d6d00000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
Capabilities: [c8] Power Management version 3
    Flags: PMEClk- DSI+ D1- D2- AuxCurrent=0mA PME(D0+,D1-,D2-,D3hot+,D3cold+)
    Status: D0 NoSoftRst- PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-
Capabilities: [d0] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Address: 00000000fee02004  Data: 402b
Capabilities: [e0] Express (v1) Endpoint, MSI 00
    DevCap: MaxPayload 128 bytes, PhantFunc 0, Latency L0s <512ns, L1 unlimited
```

`ip link` shows

```
wlp5s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
link/ether 52:ce:71:xx:xx:xx brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff permaddr 00:22:fb:xx:xx:xx
```

`ifconfig`:

```
wlp5s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 52:CE:71:XX:XX:XX
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:0  TX bytes:0
```

I don't understand where the issue is. Can you please help?

`sudo iwlist:`

```
wlp5s0    Scan completed :
      Cell 01 - Address: 
                Channel:1
                Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                Quality=40/70  Signal level=-70 dBm  
                Encryption key:on
                ESSID:"ACT102474534110"
      Cell 02 - Address: 
                Channel:2
                Frequency:2.417 GHz (Channel 2)
                Quality=38/70  Signal level=-72 dBm  
                Encryption key:on
                ESSID:"Abhijit"
      Cell 03 - Address: 
                Channel:3
                Frequency:2.422 GHz (Channel 3)
                Quality=48/70  Signal level=-62 dBm  
                Encryption key:on
                ESSID:"gagsbuds"
      Cell 04 - Address: 
                Channel:5
                Frequency:2.432 GHz (Channel 5)
                Quality=34/70  Signal level=-76 dBm  
                Encryption key:on
                ESSID:"sanjay"
      Cell 05 - Address: 
                Channel:6
                Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
                Quality=44/70  Signal level=-66 dBm  
                Encryption key:on
                ESSID:"The Devs"
      Cell 07 - Address: 
                Channel:8
                Frequency:2.447 GHz (Channel 8)
                Quality=35/70  Signal level=-75 dBm  
                Encryption key:on
                ESSID:"Tnet"
      Cell 08 - Address: 
                Channel:11
                Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
                Quality=70/70  Signal level=-21 dBm  
                Encryption key:on
                ESSID:"MaANAS"
      Cell 09 - Address: 
                Channel:11
                Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
                Quality=69/70  Signal level=-41 dBm  
                Encryption key:on
                ESSID:"DIRECT-np-BRAVIA"
      Cell 10 - Address: 
                Channel:13
                Frequency:2.472 GHz (Channel 13)
                Quality=24/70  Signal level=-86 dBm  
                Encryption key:on
                ESSID:"PanduHome"
```

Comment: Missing firmware (files) looks like the most obvious issue. Consult with dmesg. Secondly check the `rfkill` output.

Comment: I dont think so checking  dmesg shows that firmware is loaded and rfkill: shows both wlan's as unblocked

Comment: Please post the output of `sudo iwlist scan`

Comment: it seems to be able to scan for networks

Comment: What version of LFS are you running?

Comment: I followed the current development book for BLFS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based off your comments whatever utility you're using to connect to Wi-Fi is malfunctioning (e.g. due to missing dependencies) and your Wi-Fi adapter is working just fine.

For instance NetworkManager requires NetworkManager-wifi and wpa_supplicant.

Comment: I think the problem is  likely with wpa_supplicant because ethernet is working well enough

Comment: It's normally used only when you're actually connecting but it must be running anyways, e.g. here on Fedora 33: `ps ax | grep wpa -> /usr/sbin/wpa_supplicant -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf -u -s`

Comment: `ps ax | grep wpa -> 3781 pts/1    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto wpa`
this is what i get

Comment: You don't have it running. Maybe you could use a more user-friendly Linux distro, e.g. Ubuntu or Fedora :-)

Comment: oh thanks for the advice but is there a way its possible?

Comment: If it's a custom Linux distro it might not be set up out of the box to support Wi-Fi connections. Please consult with its manual/faq/support groups.

Comment: Ok this distro uses a SysV init system so when i use the custom boot script for wpa it shows that it fails to bring up wpa_supplicant on the interface

Comment: dhcpcd not able to configure interface?